# Developer story company logo is not served over HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, ssl

[My developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/story/kobi) is insecure!

[image]

The cause is the HP logo, which is linked using HTTP: [http://public.crunchbase.com/….jpg](http://public.crunchbase.com/t_api_images/h_90/v1397203190/0fb81b0e4a4a9329d38ecf6d95073c98.jpg)

The logo is coming from the built-in company picker, and the UI does not allow deleting the logo or changing it when the company is known.

Comment: Also, congratulations for switching to HTTPS!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - we're working on doing a direct CDN point right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed out the links for their CDN versions - mixed content should be resolved here :)